# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$ while running spark source code locally

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have cloned spark project in my local machine and I build spark project using below command, Build was successful.

```
mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

I imported spark project as a maven project in IntelliJ idea.
I set Scala 2.12.10 as global library in my project

But When I try to run any of the sample program in examples module I am getting below error.
I guess this has something to do with Scala compilation , Please help me understand what is going on here ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$
    at org.apache.spark.examples.GroupByTest$.main(GroupByTest.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.GroupByTest.main(GroupByTest.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 2 more
```

sharing the example spark code i am running

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// scalastyle:off println
package org.apache.spark.examples

import java.util.Random

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/**
 * Usage: GroupByTest [numMappers] [numKVPairs] [KeySize] [numReducers]
 */
object GroupByTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("GroupBy Test")
      .getOrCreate()

    val numMappers = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
    val numKVPairs = if (args.length > 1) args(1).toInt else 1000
    val valSize = if (args.length > 2) args(2).toInt else 1000
    val numReducers = if (args.length > 3) args(3).toInt else numMappers

    val pairs1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(0 until numMappers, numMappers).flatMap { p =>
      val ranGen = new Random
      val arr1 = new Array[(Int, Array[Byte])](numKVPairs)
      for (i <- 0 until numKVPairs) {
        val byteArr = new Array[Byte](valSize)
        ranGen.nextBytes(byteArr)
        arr1(i) = (ranGen.nextInt(Int.MaxValue), byteArr)
      }
      arr1
    }.cache()
    // Enforce that everything has been calculated and in cache
    pairs1.count()

    println(pairs1.groupByKey(numReducers).count())

    spark.stop()
  }
}
// scalastyle:on println
```

Comment: Can you pls share the code? One simple solution is to extend you object with App module.

Comment: I am using the sample program in example module within spark project

Comment: import spark package from your maven pom file.

Comment: cant do that, My ultimate aim is to make some edit in spark source code and experiment with it

Comment: You can try the solution suggested by me. object GroupByTest extends App

Comment: Since the program does not have main class that is why you are getting this error. If you extends through App class, you will get a main class and it will work.

Comment: I tried this "object GroupByTest extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit" same issue exists

Comment: Try removing your main class. I missed to see it..

Comment: can u paste the code, i am not able to follow

Comment: Added the code in answer. If that works let me know. Since I was not able to paste here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210091/discussion-between-manu-gupta-and-manu-jose).

Comment: The Spark dependency has to be added as `compile` scope in the Maven project.

Comment: which branch did you clone? branch-2.4, branch-3.0 or master?

Comment: Please check your pom.xml whether spark dependency is referenced correctly.

Comment: How are you starting your Spark task/application? Are you using the spark-submit command? It looks like the SPARK_HOME/jars directory is not being read.

Answer (score 4):

SparkSession is a part of `spark-sql`. Thus you need to change `provided` scope to `compile` for this library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</compile>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are trying to run an example from https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/GroupByTest.scala

In `pom.xml` there are lots of dependencies with `provided` scope. If you want to run the example from IntellijIdea or via `java -jar` you should change theit scope to `compile`.

`provided` scope is used if you are going to run the job using the spark shell or `spark-submit` command.